# Cross-platform mobile subscription (Android + iOS)

Tags: android, ios, paypal, in-app-purchase, spotify

Is it possible to make cross-platform subscription using native APIs and manage those subscription on own backend?

Example:
Make subscription on iOS change device and downgrade(cancel) subscription(plan) on android device.

Spotify for example does cross-platform subscription through PayPal and other payment methods but I'm not sure if our app will be rejected considering in-app guidelines for the both platforms.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to use when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: I can't find a way where I make subscription on iOS and up/downgrade this subscription on Android.

Comment: A subscription for what? Usually you have a "server" and this server uses PayPal or other APIs and you are registered the same on Android and iOS. For in-app purchases you will probably have to tie them together in an interesting way, but there are a lot of "possible" solutions.

Comment: Current [04.2019] statement from Apple Developer Guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

Disney did this with their digital content offering and like you said even Spotify did it. The problem here is there are many apps rejected in the appstore( especially Apple's appstore), if one is not given a way to purchase those digital items using the native in app purchase method. Ofcourse,one could have other modes of accepting the money. But it is mandatory to have in-app purchase in place for the app to get accepted(especially with Apple's appstore).So make sure you also implement in-app purchase modules of each native platform. Otherwise, if your offering is too grand(like Disney or Spotify) for the appstores to reject they will accept it. All the best!

Comment: So, will user payment for 2 flatform in same time?

Comment: Disney got that deal done from Apple and Google. I am not sure of the details.